# How do I prefix commandline output with a fixed string?

Tags: shell, stdout, mailman

Suppose I run the command:

```
sudo ./list_members Physicians
```

And I want to prefix the output like this:

```
Physicians user@domain.com
Physicians user2@domain.com
Physicians user3@domain.com
Physicians user4@domain.com
```

Is it possible for me to prefix StdOutput like that?

Comment: Does `list_members` produce just the list of email addresses? One email address per line?

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest you using `ts` utility from moreutils package.
Though its primary purpose is prepending output lines with a time stamp, it can use an arbitrary string along or instead of the timestamp

```
for line in {01..05}; do echo $line; done | ts  "A string in front "
A string in front  01
A string in front  02
A string in front  03
A string in front  04
A string in front  05
```

Comment: +1 for `ts` (look much easy than awk ..)

Answer (score 8):

Use the **s**tream **ed**itor:

```
sudo ./list_members Physicians | sed 's/^/Physicians /'
```

To make it a helper function, you may prefer `awk`  though:

```
prefix() { P="$*" awk '{print ENVIRON["P"] $0}'; }

sudo ./list_members Physicians | prefix 'Physicians '
```

If you wanted to prefix both stdout and stderr, that could be done with:

```
{
  sudo ./list_members Physicians 2>&1 >&3 3>&- |
   prefix 'Physicians ' >&2 3>&-
} 3>&1 | prefix 'Physicians '
```

Comment: Won't capture STDERR

Comment: @kos, see edit.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it with `awk`:

```
$ sudo ./list_members | awk '{print "Physicians "$0}'
Physicians user@domain.com
Physicians user2@domain.com
Physicians user3@domain.com
Physicians user4@domain.com
```

Or with `xargs`:

```
$ sudo ./list_members | xargs -n1  echo 'Physician'
```

If you know your `./list_members` will be including more than 1 argument you can use this `xargs` which splits the input being fed to it on `\n` instead:

```
$ sudo ./list_members | xargs -n1 -d $'\n' echo 'Physician'
Physician user@domain.com xxx
Physician user2@domain.com yyy
Physician user3@domain.com zzz
Physician user4@domain.com aaa
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Bourne shell (or BASH, which is a superset) to do it will keep the solution 100% POSIX:

```
sudo ./list_members | while read LINE; do echo "Prefix ${LINE}"; done
```